# How do (disabled for previous link) and active states class on pagination

Tags: php, css, mysql, pagination

i hope u can help me guys ♥ (PHP - MySQL - HTML5 - CSS3)
I'm trying to do (disabled for previous link) and active states class on
pagination i need something like this:

```
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

i need to do it with this code:

```
 <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $total_cat = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_cat / $limit);
        ?>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="categories.php?page=<?php if (($page - 1) > 0) {
                                                                                    echo  $page - 1;
                                                                                  } else {
                                                                                    echo 1;
                                                                                  }

                                                                                  ?>">Previous</a></li>
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
            ?>
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="categories.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="categories.php?page=<?php
                                                                                  if (($page + 1) < $total_pages) {
                                                                                    echo $page + 1;
                                                                                  } elseif (($page + 1) >= $total_pages) {
                                                                                    echo $total_pages;
                                                                                  }
                                                                                  ?>">Next</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```